# Regex pattern to match a word based on previous and next word?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to highlight a word based on the previous and next word matching with specific customer requirements.

A word should be highlighted only when previous and next word doesn't start with CAPS.

I have created regex "(?!\bA-Z\b)\sSouls+(?!\s[A-Z,0-9])" but it's also highlighting "Souls" with previous word that starts with capital.

https://regex101.com/r/wPmijX/2

In this case, "Souls" next to "Dark" should not be highlighted as it starts with caps. Only "Souls" in the second paragraph should be highlighted. Event "Souls" in the third paragraph should not be highlighted as "Game" start with capital letter.

Comment: You may use groups and then post-process the results, see `((?:^|\b[a-z]\w*)\s+)(Souls)(?!\s+[A-Z0-9])`

Comment: Thanks, That worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?<=\b[a-z]\w+\b \b)Souls(?=\b [a-z]\w+\b)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wPmijX/3)

Comment: Take care that lookbehind in javascript is only supported by Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, That worked for me in chrome browser but any other option for others browser.

Comment: @nishant Why not use capturing groups if it should work in other browsers?

Comment: as Toto mentioned, lookbehind might not be supported in non-chrome browsers yet. (I've overlooked that possibility). you might want to consider @Thefourthbird's answer.

Comment: In chrome, it's worked but in Firefox getting the error "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group".

Comment: @Matt.G I added this code "/(?<=^|(\b[a-z]\w*)\s)Souls(?![-a-z])(?!\s[A-Z,0-9])/g".

Answer (score 0):

If the match should be between 2 words, you could use 2 capturing groups. First capture the word before that does not start with an uppercase char and the following spaces.

Then capture `Souls` in a group and use a positive lookahead to assert what follows is 1+ times a space and does not start with an uppercase char.

Then you can use the captured groups in the replacement.

```
\b([^\WA-Z]\w* +)(Souls)(?= +[^\WA-Z])
```

That will match

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(` Start capturing group

  - `[^\WA-Z]\w* +` Match a word char but not a capital, 0+ times a word char and 1+ times a space
- `)` Close capturing group
- `(Souls)` Capture `Souls` in a group
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what follows

  - `+[^\WA-Z]` Match 1+ times a space followed by a word char but not a capital
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vyflVl/1)

```js
const regex = /\b([^\WA-Z]\w* +)(Souls)(?= +[^\WA-Z])/gm;
const str = `When I finally finished Dark Souls for the first time, that feeling of struggle and triumph, of having wandered a vast and lonesome landscape, stuck with me for weeks. 

The creator of the Souls series and game director on Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice.

The Souls Game start with competent price.`;
const subst = `$1<strong>$2</strong>`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

document.write(result);
```